# Failing HDD: Should I try to back it up or should I just send it for data recovery?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery

I've just had the dreaded BIOS message of an imminantly failing HDD. It was not my boot drive (luckily) but my other internal HDD that I use for storing all of my photos (oh no!). I have partial backups around the place but due to running out of space constantly some of them got deleted.

**Should I try to take an image of the drive (i.e. with dd and gzip) or should I just send it away to a data recovery place?**

I'm just afraid that copying all the data from the drive may cause it to fail in a way that would make data recovery impossible.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I've searched around however I can't seem to find a concrete answer to this question. All the other answers I've seen are something like "just back up the data before the drive fails" but that's not always an option.

Comment: Yes image the entire drive before doing anything else. Make 2 images.

Comment: Then mount the image and copy the files from the image

Comment: @Moab and you don't think that would make data recovery impossible if it were to come to that?

Comment: Data recovery places to the exact same thing, they first make an image of the drive. I would make one myself, no telling what will happen during shipping.

Comment: @Moab OK I shall do that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of the failure. HDD is a disk, mostly fail will get errors, not blast of the disk himself. So try to copy it asap sound like a good option. Mostly data recovery services will do anyway before attempting any tougher approach (Their time is money.).

Also, mechanics failure are noisy, so unless your disk is screaming or ticking you should actually pick this option.